# Mule ESB Accessing a SOAP WS Error

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, mule

I am trying to access a simple SOAP web service which return the String (No input arguments). Here is the configuration XML.

```
<flow name="SOAPWSFlow1" doc:name="SOAPWSFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8084"  doc:name="HTTP" />
<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getTestName" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP" clientClass="com.mart.catalog.BestMartCatalogService" port="BestMartCatalogPort"/>
</flow>
```

I get the following error when the code is executed. Appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thanks!

```
ERROR 2013-12-08 20:22:49,021 [[soapws].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]  org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint:  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. wrong number of arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:-2 (null)
2. wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint:  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150  (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

---

Comment: Add the service WSDL that is being consumed and the BestMartCatalogService  class. That will help in finding the solution

Comment: Please add the wsdl or the client class you are calling

Comment: A added the wsdl url. It still gives the same error. Why would it say 'wrong number of arguments'?